# Number of matrices with given Smith normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, lattices, matrix-theory, smith-normal-form

Denote with $\mathcal{M}$ the set of $(m \times n)$-matrices with integer coefficients bounded by some $K$. Given a matrix $B \in \mathcal{M}$ that is in Smith normal form, is anything known about the number of matrices $A \in \mathcal{M}$ that have Smith normal form $B$?

Comment: this is essentially about counting presentations of a f.g. Abelian group with a given upper bound on size.

Comment: What do you want to know? There are obvious bounds...

Comment: Yinghui Wang has just written a paper on this topic. Soon it should be posted on the arXiv.

Comment: thanks for your comments. @Igor I want to know as much as possible ;) The exact number if possible, if not then some "good" bounds.

Comment: @Richard Can you tell me the title of Wang's paper?

Comment: Miodrag Zivkovic has enumerated some small binary matrices by Smith Normal Form ( http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511636 ).  Not quite what you ask, but  it may give asymptotic hints.

Comment: @Martin The paper is now available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00160. I have been added as a coauthor.

Answer (score 1):

Just to comment: another view of the question concerns representing elements of $\mathcal{M}$ in the form $PBQ$, for $P$ and $Q$ invertible integer matrices; in particular how big one need to take entries of $P$ and $Q$ to make sure that every element of $\mathcal{M}$ with the normal form $B$ is obtained as $PBQ$.